# Scroll object when reached certain point

Tags: java, animation, applet, awt, thread-sleep

i wish to make the object scroll up when it reaches y pos = 170. then when it reaches 51 it will scroll down again. Here's my code..

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class ani1 extends Applet implements Runnable{

    Thread run01;
    int spacex = 51,spacey = 91;
    int score = 0;

    public void start() {
        if (run01 == null){
            run01 = new Thread(this);
            run01.start();
        }
    }
    public void stop() {
        if(run01 != null){
            run01 = null;
        }
    }
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(30);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } 
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.gray);
        g.fillRoundRect(35, 70, 250, 300, 10, 250);
        g.fillRect(230,20,50,50);
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRoundRect(45,85,230,100,10,250);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawRect(50, 90, 150, 90);
        g.drawString("SPACE-X",215,100);
        g.drawString("Level: 1",210,120);
        g.drawString("Score : "+ score, 210,135);
        g.drawString("Life : - - -",210,150);
        g.fillRect(spacex, spacey, 10, 10);
        spacey++;
        if(spacey >170){
            spacey--;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Create a model which can control where the objects are located.  When painted, use this model to paint the location of the object...

Comment: i just want to make it a loop. i'm not actually making a game out of this. just a simple looping animation.

Comment: the problem is that when it goes 169 or 170 it just stops there and doesn't scroll up anymore.

Comment: I don't see any movement code?

Comment: when i run the exact code the fillrect scrolls down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you should be trying to model the object you are trying to move, even if that is just modeling a `Point`, which you can then use to render some arbitrary shape.

This means you won't be tempted to make logic decisions within the paint process.  The paint process should be focused on painting the model only.

For example...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Spacy {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Spacy();
    }

    public Spacy() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private List<Movable> movables;

        public TestPane() {
            movables = new ArrayList<>(25);
            movables.add(new SpaceObject());

            Timer timer;
            timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    for (Movable m : movables) {
                        m.move(getSize());
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            for (Paintable p : movables) {
                p.paint(g);
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }

    public interface Paintable {

        public void paint(Graphics g);

    }

    public interface Movable extends Paintable {

        public void setLocation(Point p);
        public Point getLocation();
        public void move(Dimension size);

    }

    public class SpaceObject implements Movable {

        private Point p;

        public SpaceObject() {
            setLocation(new Point(150, 50));
        }

        @Override
        public void setLocation(Point p) {
            this.p = p;
        }

        @Override
        public Point getLocation() {
            return p;
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {

            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            Point p = getLocation();
            int radius = 10;
            g.fillOval(p.x - (radius / 2), p.y - (radius / 2), radius, radius);

        }

        @Override
        public void move(Dimension size) {
            Point p = getLocation();
            int delatX = 0;
            int delatY = 0;
            int gap = size.height / 4;
            if (p.y == gap) {
                delatX = 2;
            } else if (p.y == size.height - gap) {
                delatX = -2;
            }
            gap = size.width / 4;
            if (p.x == gap) {
                delatY = -2;
            } else if (p.x == size.width - gap) {
                delatY = 2;
            }
            p.x += delatX;
            p.y += delatY;

            if (p.x < (size.width / 4)) {
                p.x = size.width / 4;
            } else if (p.x > (size.width - (size.width / 4))) {
                p.x = size.width - (size.width / 4);
            }
            if (p.y < (size.height / 4)) {
                p.y = size.height / 4;
            } else if (p.y > (size.height - (size.height / 4))) {
                p.y = size.height - (size.height / 4);
            }

            setLocation(p);
        }            
    }        
}
```

You have two, basic problems with your code.

1. You are trying to make decisions about how to paint the output within the paint method.  Generally this is unadvisable.  As you leads towards other bad habits
2. You are not updating the `Graphics` context before you paint.  Basically what is happening, is you are been given the same `Graphics` context you used on the last paint cycle, meaning that when you reach the end and want to start scrolling back up, what you previously painted is still there.

I would recommend that;

1. You avoid `Applet` and use `JApplet`, in fact, I'd avoid applets altogether and simply use `JFrame` as the base container, they come with less issues.
2. Create a custom component based on something like `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method and perform your custom painting there.
3. Make sure you are calling `super.paintComponent` first, as this will prepare the `Graphics` context for you
4. Personally, I would avoid the use of `Thread` for this case, it introduces additional complications, instead, I would use a `javax.swing.Timer`, but that's just me.

You might like to take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details